# Center Form using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: forms, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap to build a form (served by django). I want to have the form centered on the page but I'm running into some problems.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/form/">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Please login</legend>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="id_username">Username</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input name="username" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your username..." type="text" class="input-large" id="id_username" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="id_password">Password</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input name="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your password..." type="password" class="input-large" id="id_password" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've excluded some additional django logic ({% csrf_token %}, some if statements, etc), but this should recreate the problem.

The actual input elements (username and password textboxes) are centering like I expected, but the labels remain to the far left of the page. Am I missing markup somewhere or do I have to override some of the control-label CSS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to include your form inside a container, the bootstrap already comes with a container class that is `width:940px` so you can wrap everything inside and it'll center automatically, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/form/">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Please login</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="id_username">Username</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="username" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your username..." type="text" class="input-large" id="id_username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="id_password">Password</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your password..." type="password" class="input-large" id="id_password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have everything wrapped in the "container" class, and I'm still getting the same results. I just didn't include it in my (modified) sample. I've edited my original comment to reflect this (I tried copying/pasting everything I had into a test page, and it's still not centering).

Comment: @Nitzle yeah that is because the control groups is floated to the left, you can easily get the results you're looking for by simply lowering the `span` tag container width and centering that instead, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PSMwt/1/

Comment: That did seem to work, however I also got it to work by adding text-align:center; margin: 0 auto; to the "span12" wrapper, and adding "width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; to the form tag, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uvNVY/

Comment: @Nitzle right, its pretty much the same approach, the width of the `span6` class is `460px`.

Comment: I'm getting another issue as a result of centering this form. I have included a checkbox and the checkbox now seems to be positioning itself too close to the "label", as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/VuaYz/2/ Any thoughts?

Comment: @Nitzle for inline checkboxes you need to supply the `<label class="checkbox inline">` inline class as well, here is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VuaYz/3/