# How do you center form controls with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to center form controls in Bootstrap.  I try wrapping everything in a .center div but that centers some things and screws up others.

```
.center
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Google is your best friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352866/center-form-using-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: @goodmanship I tried that.  But specifically what I need is two radio buttons, centered, and inline.  And I can't seem to get it.

Comment: sup bro.  i think you mean @david ^

Comment: Try providing us with the HTML you are using, and we'll be able to help better.

Comment: I found simple_form and am trying the following:

    <div class="center">

    <%= label_tag "Do you have pets?" %>

    <%= f.input :dogs, as: :boolean %>
    <%= f.input :cats, as: :boolean %>

</div>

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap css center span7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554724/bootstrap-css-center-span7)

Comment: @MByD Unlikely as that is referencing the old version of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text-center class

```
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
```

Other text alignment classes are

```
<p class="text-left">Left aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-justify">Justified text.</p>
<p class="text-nowrap">No wrap text.</p>
```

For detailed information please visit http://getbootstrap.com/css/